# CUDA help in implementing kernel function with 320*240 image to process

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, mfc, cuda, kernel

i am pretty new to cuda and am trying to read a frame in cuda through this code but i am getting an overthrow error and getting a black output ..
here is my code..

```
BYTE *imageBuf = 0;
BYTE *maBuf = 0;
BYTE *fgBuf = 0;
BYTE *tempBuf = 0;

cudaMalloc((void **)&maBuf , m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight);
cudaMalloc((void **)&fgBuf , m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight);
cudaMalloc((void **)&imageBuf , m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight);
cudaMalloc((void **)&tempBuf , m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight);
cudaMalloc((void **)&m_pixel_ptr , m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight);

cudaMemcpy(m_pixel_ptr , m_pixelParam , m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(imageBuf , inImgBuf , m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(fgBuf , foregroundBUf , m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(maBuf , maskBuf , m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(tempBuf , foregroundBUf , m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

kernel<<<16,20>>>(imageBuf, maBuf, fgBuf , 320 , 240 , m_pixel_ptr , tempBuf , 0);


cudaMemcpy (maskBuf, maBuf , m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy (foregroundBUf, fgBuf , m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy (inImgBuf, imageBuf , m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy (m_pixelParam , m_pixel_ptr , m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaFree(m_pixel_ptr);
cudaFree(imageBuf);
cudaFree(maBuf);
cudaFree(tempBuf);
cudaFree(fgBuf);
```

This is how i am calling my kernel function and here is my kernel function

```
    __global__ void kernel(BYTE *inImgBuf, BYTE *maskBuf,  BYTE *foregroundBUf , int width , int height , PixelPara *m_pixelParam , BYTE *tmpBuffer , int j)
{


int m_IniWeight = 0.005;
int m_IniStd = 400.0;
int m_Threshold = 0.7;
int fgTh;

int thresholdRank;


for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
        int tid = ((threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x)*width + i);
        if (m_pixelParam[tid].m_validModels == 0) 
        {
            m_pixelParam[j*width+i].m_weight[0] = m_IniWeight;
            m_pixelParam[j*width+i].m_stdVar[0] = m_IniStd;
            m_pixelParam[j*width+i].m_priRank[0] = 0;
            m_pixelParam[j*width+i].m_mean[0] = (double)inImgBuf[j*width+i];
            m_pixelParam[j*width+i].m_validModels++;


        }
        else
        {
            thresholdRank = 0;
            fgTh = 0.0;             
            while (true)
            {
                fgTh += m_pixelParam[j*width+i].m_weight[m_pixelParam[j*width+i].m_priRank[thresholdRank]];                 

                if ((fgTh > m_Threshold) || (thresholdRank >= m_pixelParam[j*width+i].m_validModels - 1)) 
                    break;      

                thresholdRank++;
            }

                gmmImplementation (inImgBuf, maskBuf, foregroundBUf ,width , height , m_pixelParam , (j*width+i) ,tmpBuffer ,thresholdRank );




            foregroundBUf = tmpBuffer;


        }

}






}
```

Can anybody help me out here how can i process a 320* 240 frame in cuda I am trying to implement GMM on cuda but am failing.. Any help or guideline.. Thank you.

Comment: add error checking to *every* API  call to ensure that everything works before further debugging your kernel code. Also, what is an "overthrow" error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are allocating m_pixel_ptr with size `m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight` while it looks like it should be `m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight * sizeof(PixelPara)`. That would explain why you're getting buffer overruns. You're probably attempting to read and write way past the end of the array. Of course, your cudaMemcpy calls for m_pixel_ptr would also need to be of length `m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight * sizeof(PixelParam)` in order to copy the entire buffer to and from the device.

Also, is imageBuf supposed to contain doubles or just single bytes? Right now, your code just reads a single byte for each pixel from `inImgBuf` and then casts it to a double before storing it in `m_pixelParam[j*width+i].m_mean[0]`. If it's supposed to be reading doubles, you'd need to allocate and copy imageBuf with size `m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight * sizeof(double)` and you'd need to declare `inImgBuf` as a `double *` in your kernel parameter list instead of as a `BYTE *`.

Comment: Hi,
thank you for the help.. imageBuf is a byte array and i am reading it one at a time... and gonna store the pixelParam as you have suggested. Is there any thing else i shoud do. ?

Comment: hi,
Can you please help me out with this that i am running this code but its not giving me the correct output like m_pixelParam[tid].m_validModels is 0 for every frame which should not be

Comment: I'm not really sure of exactly what your code is trying to do, but it seems suspect to me that j is initialized zero and then never set again. So, every thread is setting the fields in indicies [0 - width] of m_pixelParam. Since j is always 0, then [j*width + i] is always equal to [i]. Also, you have one thread per each column (320 of them,) but it looks like you may be trying to have each thread process a row instead of a column. Perhaps you need to use <<16,15>> instead of <<16,20>> in your kernel invocation and replace instances of [j*width + i] with [tid].

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how these lines are compiling:

`int m_IniWeight = 0.005;
int m_IniStd = 400.0;
int m_Threshold = 0.7;`

Integers (ints) are whole numbers (e.g. -1, 0, 1, 2, etc.) In order to store numbers which have fractional components (such as 0.005 or 0.7,) you need to use variables of type float, not int. If you force a number with a fractional component into an integer variable (by casting,) the fractional portion will be truncated, so 0.005 and 0.7 would both be truncated to 0.